# How to sleep within the same function in QT?

Tags: qt, sleep

I'm student for studying QT.
I want to sleep(delay) within the same function, but I can't to sleep function as I thought.

```
void test(){
        cardTurning(i, 0);
        // I want to sleep for 3 seconds at here
        cardTurning(i, 1);
}
```

What shoud I do for sleep there?

I already used QThread::sleep(3);, but it makes sleep there two functions together.

I want to sleep three seconds after cardTurning(i, 0) and then work cardTurning(i, 1).

Thank you.

Comment: QThread::sleep cause calling thread to go to sleep exactly where it's called, what's the problem?

Comment: I want to delay three seconds after working 'cardTurning(i, 0)', and then working 'cardTuring(i, 1)'.

Comment: what do you mean by working? First (i, 0) is called and after it's completion (i, 1) is called.

Comment: yes. That's correct I told. I solved this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you going to use the sleep function you will sleep the whole program.
at this type of delay, you can use the QTimer::singleShot function it calls only one time after your interval and not sleep the whole system. it takes interval as an ms.

you can see a basic example below ;

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
void print1(int x,int y){
    qDebug()<<"value = "<<x<<" "<<y;
}

void Test(){
    print1(3,2);
    QTimer::singleShot(3000,[](){
       print1(4,5);

    });

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Test();
    print1(10,10);
    return a.exec();
}
```

expected outputs are ;
value =  3   2
value =  10   10
value =  4   5